# Count instances of class before $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have a list that displays divs with class called `delImg`.

How can I get the count of instances of the same class before the one clicked?

Code I have tried is...

```
$("#slidingtabs").on('click', '.delImg',function(){
    var prevDels = $(this).prevAll('.delImg').length;
});
```

It doesn't work, it just returns 0

Comment: Try `$('.delImg').index(this)`.  This should tell you the index of the element clicked.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextAll()`/`prevAll()` only work on siblings, so if you're getting `0` it's safe to assume that the elements you're trying to find are not directly related.

As such you can use `index()` with a global selector to find the current element in the set. Try this:

```js
$("#slidingtabs").on('click', '.delImg', function() {
  var prevDels = $(this).index('.delImg');
  console.log(prevDels);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slidingtabs">
  <p>
    <span class="delImg">Click me</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="delImg">Click me</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="delImg">Click me</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="delImg">Click me</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="delImg">Click me</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: worked a treat, thank you.  I'll accept when it lets me.